# How to restore files on SD Card that was protected by Vault app?

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery

I changed my Android mobile phone from one carrier to another. I installed [Vault app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netqin.ps&hl=en) from the Google Play store, and placed the old SD Card from the previous phone into this new phone. After installing the vault software in the new phone, I am unable to restore data (photos, videos) from *old* SD card.

What might be the reason for this? Is there any way I can recover the files from my old SD card, which was protected by the Vault app.

Comment: Rephrased the question so it doesn't get closed.

Comment: Any updates from your end?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wild guess. The Vault may have encrypted the protected files to be used only with the previous phone. So if you try to open them in another phone (assuming you have installed the Vault with the same Google account), the new phone won't be able to access them.

I have emailed help@nq.com regarding this issue. Hopefully, they will reply. I will then update / confirm this answer. If not, it's safe to say my assumption was right.

**Update #1:**

> Thank you for contacting NQ Mobile Customer Support!
>
> You would not be able to show pictures on your SD card in another
>   phone. Once you put them in Vault they are encrypted in the phone and
>   would not be able to be seen. The Vault application is specific to
>   each phone unless you transfer the application to another phone.
>
> Thank you again for contacting NQ Mobile Customer Support!
>
> Adam Schalk
>   NQ Mobile Customer Support Team

**Possible Solution**

What can do is put back the card into the old phone, and remove the protection from the Vault. I'm sure you can un-protect pictures, like in other apps. After you've unprotected all the pictures / files, put back the SD card to your new phone. You should be able to read the files. After that, you can protect them again using Vault (on your new phone).