# How to restore files on SD card protected by NQ vault?

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, nqvault

I changed my Android mobile phone from one carrier to another. I installed Vault app from the Google Play store, and placed the old SD Card from the previous phone into this new phone. After installing the vault software in the new phone, I am unable to restore data (photos, videos) from old SD card.
My old phone isn't in working condition so how do I restore these files?

Answer (score 2):

There is a related post here which indicates that vault app is phone specific [How to restore files on SD Card that was protected by Vault app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49657/how-to-restore-files-on-sd-card-that-was-protected-by-vault-app) which indicates it is not possible, more so since your old device isn't working

Even for premium vault members it appears to be the same (need to use old phone)
https://help.nq.com/entries/24327737-I-just-got-a-new-phone-how-can-I-transfer-my-Premium-Vault-service-to-the-new-device-

But both these are time lined 2013 so it's best to reach out to nq vault help and post your outcome here for benefit of others

**Edit**

**Short answer** : **NO**, unless you are a premium subscriber and made a cloud backup

**Long Answer** : I mailed NQ, since I had the app on my previous cell and 
was debating to go premium. Their reply, you can quote  request (#239838) to follow up

> Carrie (NQ Mobile US, Inc.)
>   Dec 23, 09:28

Thank you for contacting NQ Mobile Customer Support.

> Unfortunately, if you no longer able to access the device, it will be difficult to recover your files and information from the Vault at this time. This is because the Vault files are saved locally on the device itself and the only way to either backup, restore, or move those encrypted files would be by using the Vault application on the original device. There is no other way to do so via a computer for example, unfortunately.
>
> If you ever made a backup with our premium Cloud Backup (Vault Online) feature in the past, you should be able to restore your information to the last backup on a new mobile device by tapping " Cloud Backup (Vault Online) " in the application, signing into your NQ Account, and then tapping the green "Restore" button. If you have never made a backup or were never a Premium User, unfortunately the files are lost and there's no other way to recover them. I do apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.
>
> If you had Premium Service on your old device, however, I can assist you in transferring that Premium Service over to your new phone.

There is a **lesson** to be learnt here, before trusting sensitive data to such apps, **evaluate all contingencies before you do that**

Answer (score 0):

I imported pics and videos which were in my SD card to vault, then inserted my SD card to another phone and all the pics and videos are available.

If you import data from sd card to vault so what vault does is it copies the data to vault in internal memory
And 1 original copy is still in the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

I imported pics and videos which were in my SD card to vault, then inserted my SD card to another phone and all the pics and videos were available.

If you import data from SD card to vault, what vault does is it copies the data to vault in internal memory and 1 original copy is still in the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read your sdcard using the PC , the Vault is a form of programme that move you files to hidden. Use of find the folder, your files are there.

That's how I do last time.